# Footer bar can't align text

Tags: html, css

Hey my footer bar at the bottom of my page wont align text.

This is my html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="footer">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <h3>Computerbasen</h3>
    <h3>Info</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #FF7633;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

[Click here and see the image of the footer bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nELL.png)

Comment: It is horizontally aligned though. Do you want it to be vertically aligned? Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean horizontal alignment, use this rule:

```
#footer h3 {
 text-align:center;
}
```

(the `h3` elements have 100% width and left-alignment by default)

Answer (score 1):

You know there is a footer tag in html, try this:

```
<footer>
<h3>Contact</h3>
<h3>Computerbasen</h3>
<h3>Info</h3>
</footer>

footer {
  background-color: #FF7633;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#footer {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Most of the text is not showing up because the height is too small.